# Problems with table border styling in Chrome (works in FF)

Tags: css, google-chrome, html-table

In a table with collapsed borders I need to give a special border style to some cells. In Chrome this does not work properly. (Without collapsed borders the result is as expected.)

[image]

```
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
td { border: 1px solid gray; }
```

Strong border: https://jsfiddle.net/r8h7abnf/ Whole bottom border of cell above affeced.

```
td.red { border: 3px solid red; }
```

No border: https://jsfiddle.net/yrm8sfLp/ Does not always work.

```
td.gap { border: 0; }
```

Can I somehow adapt the styles to make it work in both browsers?

Comment: give `display: block` to the class red

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I added the result to the picture. But that is not the intended result. And making it look worse in FF to avoid a bug in Chrome seems just wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: fixed in Chrome 92 released in July 2021. Still broken in Safari in Dec 2022.**

---

This is a very longstanding bug in Chrome: https://crbug.com/2902 :(

You can workaround it if you figure out a way to only use colspan == 1.

Note that FWIW, adding display:block to the `td.red`puts a border around a box that's inside an implicitly-added cell. You can see that the red border doesn't cover the grey border, but instead is inside it.

Comment: Different colspans are essential to the app I need this for: http://treetable.watchduck.net/ So it seems the right solution is to wait for the Chome developers to fix the bug.

Comment: This bug was fixed in Chromium (Works in Safari), however since Chrome forked Chromium before the fix, it is still broken in Chrome.

Comment: @MichaelRobellard No, Chrome now renders this case correctly and has since summer 2021. It was specifically discussed in the blog post at https://developer.chrome.com/blog/tablesng/#improved-border-painting-and-background-painting. Today's Safari Tech Preview still renders this case incorrectly. The relevant open WebKit bug is https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5515.